# Closure in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

So I am reading the some code and I see a trailing closure, from my understanding and some googling, it seems trailing closure is used when you have a final parameter as a closure so you can pass it as a trailing closure.

And this is what confuses me.
I have a class A and a class B. Class B inherits from Class A. In Class A, there is a function C looks like this:

```
func C(text1: String, text2: String) -> SomeOddType{...}
```

now in Class B, it overrides this function, but the body is like this:

```
override func C(text1: String, text2:String) -> SomeOddType{
 if let someVar = super.C(text:text1, text:text2){
  //some code that's not in the super method
  return someVar
  }
}
```

What does that do??? I am so confused. It doesn't have a closure as a parameter, and since it's already calling the super method, the code inside the override version is an add-on to the implementation?

Comment: Where is the closure in your question?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri on the someVar line. I assume it's a closure right? after function call with {}

Comment: Ah i thought your method had a closure argument. My bad. Now i do not understand your question though. Are you saying your return is a closure in the method? Also provide a complete example, not just snippets. One that works in the playground perhaps?

Comment: sort of? My question is, when the super.C method is called, it already returns an Object with SomeOddType, what does that block of code does inside {} after super.C? super.C {//code} ?

Comment: That block of code shouldn't be there according to me, which is why i'm asking if you have compiled your code on the playrgounds.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri It ran. NVM I get it now. It's an if let... SO if statements, that block belongs to the if. My bad. Didn't realize it was unwrapping.

Comment: _whoops_ i got tunnel visioned thinking it was a closure of some sort. @_@

Comment: Please try and improve your question title - read [ask] for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no trailing closure here, it's just the block of an `if` statement. The expression `super.C(text: text1, text: text2)` is conditionally bound to the new constant `someVar`. If the conditional binding succeeds, it runs the "//some code that's not in the super method" block of code.

Answer (score 0):

`super.C(text:text1, text:text2)` returns `SomeOddType`, but it should be optional.
And it assigns to `someVar`

Comment: but what does the {} after the function call do tho? It's SomeOddType{//code}, what does this do?